# PHP React\ZMQ\Context 'ON' methods not fire

Tags: php, websocket, zeromq, ratchet

I am trying to implement a web socket server using php.

I have followed instructions in [ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/push). But I couldn't push changes to client. I understood that problem is "`React\ZMQ\Context`" that does not react to any event.

As I expected, this component should react to `open`, `close`, `message` and `error` events. Here is my code :

```
$loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$pusher = new MyApp\Pusher;

// Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context( $loop );
$pull    = $context->getSocket( ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL );
$pull->bind( 'tcp://127.0.0.1:9021' ); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
$pull->on( 'open',    function( $msg ){ echo "open";    } );
$pull->on( 'close',   function( $msg ){ echo "close";   } );
$pull->on( 'message', function( $msg ){ echo "message"; } );
$pull->on( 'error',   function( $msg ){ echo "error";   } );

// Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
$webSock = new React\Socket\Server( '0.0.0.0:8090', $loop ); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                $pusher
            )
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);
$loop->run();
```

---

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, unless you also modify the **`PUSH`**-side of the ZeroMQ infrastructure setup:

```
<?php
    // post.php ???
    // This all was here before  ;)
    $entryData = array(
        'category' => $_POST['category']
      , 'title'    => $_POST['title']
      , 'article'  => $_POST['article']
      , 'when'     => time()
    );

    $pdo->prepare( "INSERT INTO blogs (title, article, category, published) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)" )
        ->execute( $entryData['title'], $entryData['article'], $entryData['category'], $entryData['when'] );


// This is our new stuff
    $context = new ZMQContext();
    $socket  = $context->getSocket( ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher' );
    $socket->connect( "tcp://localhost:5555" );
//                                     ^^^^__________ MUST BECOME 9021 after your mod-s
    $socket->send( json_encode( $entryData ) );
```

---

If this does not work, check all error-states, provided as per documented ZeroMQ native API services ( actual code depends on your native API language wrapper / binding ).

For another level of testing, there may be a lightweight set of tests to setup a trivial environment in python:

```
import     zmq
aClk     = zmq.Stopwatch()
aContext = zmq.Context()

aTarget  = "tcp://127.0.0.1:9021" # <- ADJUST TO PULL-er side transport-class endpoint

aPushToProveZMQ_RTO = aContext.Socket( zmq.PUSH )
aPushToProveZMQ_RTO.setsockopt(        zmq.LINGER, 0 )
aPushToProveZMQ_RTO.connect(           aTarget )

aClk.start()

try:
    print( "INF: infinite loop, sending messages [[[ Use Ctrl+C to break ]]]" )
    while True:
          aPushToProveZMQ_RTO.send( "aLoop RTT::({0:}[us])".format( aClk.stop() ) )
          pass;                                                     aClk.start()

except:
    pass

finally:
    aPushToProveZMQ_RTO.close()
    aContext.term()

    print( "INF: a gracefull exit" )
```

Comment: I have use this part in my project. Also with monitoring open ports, I understand that the port 5555 has open on my system. But when I send data on this port it do no reaction.

Comment: Try the python-[PULL]-tester and python-[PUSH]-tester, to first test the whole test-path. Next test the native ZeroMQ operations with a python-[PULL]-tester and the php-[PUSH]-er, if not receiving, the php-sender is to be blamed, if receiving, try the python-[PUSH]-tester and if not receiving in php-receiver, you are on spot.